# How to handle specific integer exception in python with try function. How to handle multiple except with try function

Tags: python, try-except

This code should tell exactly what error the user is making and prompt to try again.

How can I make custom error messages for each error?

Would there be a much more simpler solution like the do-while in c-programming?

```
while True:
    height = int(input("Height: "))
    try:
        check_answer = int(height)
        assert (int(height) > 0)
        assert (int(height) < 9)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("must enter a number")
    except (???):
        print("enter a number greater than 0")
    except (???):
        print("enter a number smaller than 9")
```

Comment: Must you use try-except blocks for the greater than & less than conditions? Can't those just be 'if' statements after the ValueError exception?

Comment: Both `assert`s would produce exactly the same class of exception if they fail, and that's the only thing you can base an `except` clause on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use the `assert` statement, you can pass the message as a second argument so that it becomes the message of the `AssertionError` exception:

```
while True:
    try:
        height = int(input("Height: "))
        assert height > 0, "enter a number greater than 0"
        assert height < 9, "enter a number smaller than 9"
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("must enter a number")
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(str(e))
```

But what you want to achieve is usually done with simple `if` statements instead:

```
while True:
    try:
        height = int(input("Height: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("must enter a number")
    if height <= 0:
        print("enter a number greater than 0")
    elif height >= 9:
        print("enter a number smaller than 9")
    else:
        break
```